# Hibernate: primer select funciona, pero el segundo ya no

Tags: java, hibernate

En este ejercicio, el primer select hibernate en el alumnoDAO funciona.

```
public class AlumnoDAO
{
    public List<Alumno> listar() {
        String hql = "select a from Alumno a";
        Query query = GenericDAO.em.createQuery(hql);
        List<Alumno> alumnos = query.getResultList();
        return alumnos;
    }
```

Pero cuando hago el segundo select en el domicilioDAO, ya no funciona:

```
public class DomicilioDAO
{
    public Domicilio recuperarSiExiste(Domicilio domicilio)
    {
        String hql = "SELECT D FROM domicilio D WHERE D.calle = :calle AND D.noCalle = :noCalle AND D.pais = :pais";
        Query query = GenericDAO.em.createQuery(hql);
        query.setParameter("calle", domicilio.getCalle());
        query.setParameter("noCalle", domicilio.getNoCalle());
        query.setParameter("pais", domicilio.getPais());
        //List<Domicilio> domicilios = query.getResultList();
        Object domObj = query.getSingleResult();
        if (domObj == null) return domicilio;
        else return (Domicilio)domObj;     
     }
```

```
package domain;

import java.util.Objects;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="domicilio")
public class Domicilio{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private Integer id;
    private String calle;
    private String noCalle;
    private String pais;
```

Este es la clase de conexion de Hibernate a la bd

```
package dao;

import javax.persistence.*;

public  class ConexionDAO {
    public static EntityManager em;
    private static EntityManagerFactory emf;
    /*El valor de PU debe ser igual al valor del atributo name de la etiqueta persistence-unit en el archivo persistence.xml*/
    private static final String PU = "HibernateJpaPU";
    static
    {
        ConexionDAO.emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(ConexionDAO.PU);
        ConexionDAO.em = ConexionDAO.emf.createEntityManager();
    }
}
```

Este es el codigo del archivo persistence.xml (un archivo de configuracion del hibernate):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.2" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_2.xsd">
    <!-- Define Persistence Unit -->
    <persistence-unit name="HibernateJpaPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>domain.Domicilio</class>
        <class>domain.Contacto</class>
        <class>domain.Curso</class>
        <class>domain.Alumno</class>
        <class>domain.Asignacion</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"></property>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sga?useSSL=false&amp;useTimezone=true&amp;serverTimezone=UTC"></property>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"></property>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="heybuddy"></property>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"></property>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"></property>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Y me sale el siguiente mensaje de error en el navegador:

> HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error
>
> type Exception report
>
> messageInternal Server Error
>
> descriptionThe server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.query.sqm.InterpretationException: Error interpreting query [SELECT D FROM domicilio D WHERE D.calle = :calle AND D.noCalle = :noCalle AND D.pais = :pais]; this may indicate a semantic (user query) problem or a bug in the parser
>
> note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 5.0.1 logs.
> GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 5.0.1

De antemano gracias a la comunidad por darse el tiempo de leer este mensaje y tratar de dar una solución.

Comment: Lo que no funciona es la query.. la probaste?

Comment: La recontra probé, le quité el where para hacerla más simple, pero nada, me salía el mismo error.  El D es el alias de la tabla domicilio, y su ubicacion es propio del formato de hibernate.

Comment: Si si.. despues me di cuenta que era sobre hibernate y por eso borre la otra parte...

Answer (score 0):

El problema era que el *domicilio* del *"SELECT D FROM domicilio D WHERE..* comienza con "d" minuscula, tal como empieza en la tabla en la base de datos, y esto es un error, pues debe empezar tal como está en el modelo de entidades de java, esto quiere decir: *Domicilio*. El codigo quedaria asi:

```
public Domicilio recuperarSiExiste(Domicilio domicilio)
{
    String hql = "select d from Domicilio d where d.calle = :calle and d.noCalle = :noCalle and d.pais = :pais";
    Query query = ConexionDAO.em.createQuery(hql);
    query.setParameter("calle", domicilio.getCalle());
    query.setParameter("noCalle", domicilio.getNoCalle());
    query.setParameter("pais", domicilio.getPais());
    Object domObj;
    try
    {
        /*ejecuto el query*/
        domObj = query.getSingleResult();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        return domicilio;
    }
    return (Domicilio)domObj;    
}
```

El otro problema era que los atributos primary key de las entidades de java no tenian la etiqueta de:
*@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)*
ya que estos pk en la base de datos son autoincrementables
El codigo quedaria asi:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="domicilio")
public class Domicilio{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String calle;
    private String noCalle;
    private String pais;
```